# How to hidden menu and route by permission service

Tags: angularjs

I use Blur Admin to Develop Web App

and I have Service to check permission for each user

how i can hidden menu by permission service in pages.module.js and LVS.module.js

ps. my poor English.

My code

**App.js:**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('BlurAdmin', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ui.sortable',
  'ui.router',
  'ngTouch',
  'toastr',
  'smart-table',
  "xeditable",
  'ui.slimscroll',
  'ngJsTree',
  'angular-progress-button-styles',

  'BlurAdmin.theme',
  'BlurAdmin.pages',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngCookies',
])
;
```

**pages.module.js:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages', [
    'ui.router',

    'BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.ui',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.components',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.form',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.tables',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.charts',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.maps',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.profile',

    'BlurAdmin.pages.Base',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.Common',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.Home',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.MSS',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.LVS',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.SHS',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.OTS',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.TCS',
  ])
      .config(routeConfig).run(run);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($urlRouterProvider, baSidebarServiceProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('Login');

  }
})();
```

**LVS.module.js:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.LVS', [
    ])
      .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('LVS', {
          url: '/Leave',
          template : '<ui-view></ui-view>',
          //controller: 'LeaveManagementCtrl',
          abstract: true,
          title: 'Leave Management',
          sidebarMeta: {
            icon: 'ion-android-calendar',
            order: 30,
          },
          resolve: {
            user: function (AuthService, $q) {
              var d = $q.defer();
              if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                // I also provide the user for child controllers
                d.resolve(AuthService.UserDomain());
              } else {
                // here the rejection
                d.reject('not logged');
              }
              return d.promise;
            }
          },
        })
        .state('LVS.LeaveList', {
          url: '/List',
          templateUrl: 'app/pages/ESS-TA/LeaveManagement/LeaveList.html',
          controller: 'LVSCtrl',
          title: 'Leave List',
          params: {
            obj: null,
          },
          sidebarMeta: {
            order: 10,
          },
        })
        .state('LVS.LeaveReport', {
          url: '/Report',
          templateUrl: 'app/pages/ESS-TA/LeaveManagement/LeaveReport.html',
          title: 'Leave Report',
          sidebarMeta: {
            order: 30,
          },
        });
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this on githut blue admin issue

https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/issues/141

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).